# To remove Shift xlUp or Down from the code

Tags: shift

This code was found on one of the threads.
Everything related to code was useful except one
that is after execution of the code the data is
shifted upwards . I want that row i.e A to F should
become blank and data not shifted upwards. Tried to
remove Shift:=xlShiftUp from code but still data is
shifting upwards in the source file (Sheet1).
code is

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Source As Range, Target As Range

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Source = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

Set Target = Source.Find(What:=DCNameTextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    
If Not Target Is Nothing Then
    'Reference the next enmpty row on Sheet2
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            '.Range("A1:F1") is relative to the row of it's parent range
            .Range("A1:F1").Value = Target.Range("A1:F1").Value
            .Range("H1:J1").Value = Array(DCDateTextBox.Value, DispoTextBox.Value, ReasonTextBox.Value)

            Set Source = .Range("A3", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        End With
    End With
    Target.Range("A1:F1").Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    
    MsgBox "Client has been moved to Discharge list."
Else
    MsgBox "Client not found", vbInformation, "No Data"
End If

Range("A3").Select
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand completely, but if you want to clear the content of A1:F1 do

```
Target.Range("A1:F1").ClearContents
```

instead of

```
Target.Range("A1:F1").Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
```

if there is nothing to the rigth of F1, then you can do

```
Target.Range("A1:F1").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```